# How to update loss function without recompiling the model?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have a custom loss function related to the batch data like this below

input, output, points = batch_data(in, out, total_points...)

custom_loss_function(true, pred, points)

And since I need to feed the dataset from batch_data for every epoch, I set up my code like this below

```
for i in range(epochs):
  input, output, points = batch_data(in, out, total_points...)
  model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss=custom_loss_function(points))
  K.set_value(model.optimizer.learning_rate, 0.001)
  model.train_on_batch(input, output)
...
```

But the problem is that it takes too much resource since it compiles in every epoch, so took a lot of time.
In order to take the compile out of the loop I tried this below

```
model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss=dummy_loss)
K.set_value(model.optimizer.learning_rate, 0.001)

for i in range(epochs):
  input, output, points = batch_data(in, out, total_points...)
  model.losses = custom_loss_function(points)
  model.train_on_batch(input, output)
```

I tried to feed in dummy loss first, and change it to the custom loss function later, but it didn't work. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Why do you set the loss function on every iteration? Just don't do that... the loss function should work across every batch even if you only set it once.